# How to compare or read Windows7 themepack files (application display issue)

Tags: windows-7, display, themes

I have a .NET WinForms application that is behaving oddly with the DELL Windows Theme.  When the application title bar is maximized via double click or the maximize button, the text in the title bar becomes... wonky (see image below).  When maximized by dragging the application title bar to the top of the screen, the application text is perfectly legible.

[image: at text]

My question:

1) how do I see what changes are made in a Windows7 Themepack to isolate the setting(s) that are causing the problem?
2) Is there a way to get a human readable version of a themepack file?
3) Is there a tool to compare two themepace files?

Comment: I've exported the themepack to a different PC, and all 3 methods of maximizing an application cause the wonky display issue.

Answer (score 0):

Themepack files are cab files.  WinZip / 7 Zip can open them, then the theme file (plain text) can be viewed.